# selecting only one of 4 records that have several identical field values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running a script with a MySQL query (seen below) That works exactly as expected but I need to make one small change due to an issue with our data.

The phone system that this is querying sometimes inserts 3 or 4 records for the same phone call, and we don't know exactly why, but when this runs we only want one record for each phone call. I've decided that this needs to be done by looking at a distinct `Calling_number, Start_Time, End_time, and Talk_Time_Seconds`. The duplicated/identical rows have the same values for those three fields.

The query itself is exactly what we want so I don't want to have to restructure it much if possible, but I need some help with this.

How can I make this select a distinct record if calling number, start, end and talk time are exactly the same value as stated above?

```
      SELECT
          FirstN
          , LastN
          , Extension
          , Recieved
          , Recieved_Known
          , Outbound
          , Outbound_Known
          , Missed_No_VM
          , Missed_VM
          , Missed_Known
          , Calling_Number
          , Called_Number
          , Start_Time
          , End_Time
        , Talk_Time_Seconds
          , Hold_Time_Seconds

        FROM (
            SELECT
             firstn
             , lastn
             , c.extension
             , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
             , case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Recieved_Known
             , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 'x' ELSE '' end  AS Outbound
             , case when LEGTYPE1 = 1 and FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Outbound_Known
             , case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0 and finallycalledpartyno  not like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_No_VM
             , case when finallycalledpartyno like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_VM
             , case when ANSWERED = 0 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_Known
             , a.CALLINGPARTYNO AS Calling_Number
             , a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO AS Called_Number
             , b.starttime as Start_Time
             , b.endtime as End_Time
             , b.duration as Talk_Time_Seconds
             , a.holdtimesecs as Hold_Time_Seconds

            FROM ambition.session a
            INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
            right join jackson_id.users c on a.callingpartyno = c.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = c.extension
            LEFT JOIN ambition.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
                WHERE a.ts >= curdate()
                and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from ambition.ambition_users))
            ) x
            order by extension;
```

Comment: To marshall your existing data the way you want, you would have to do some sort of aggregation or filtering to remove duplicate records.  But I might suggest a unique index here, which would prevent duplicates from even being inserted (such inserts would just fail).

Comment: Unfortunately I can't apply a unique index to the table this is selecting from because we don't control the DB, our phone manager does.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before you spend too much time.)

Comment: _Columns_, not fields...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using row_number partition by on the four columns :

```
 SELECT
          FirstN
          , LastN
          , Extension
          , Recieved
          , Recieved_Known
          , Outbound
          , Outbound_Known
          , Missed_No_VM
          , Missed_VM
          , Missed_Known
          , Calling_Number
          , Called_Number
          , Start_Time
          , End_Time
        , Talk_Time_Seconds
          , Hold_Time_Seconds

        FROM (
            SELECT
             firstn
             , lastn
             , c.extension
             , CASE WHEN LEGTYPE1 = 2 AND ANSWERED = 1 THEN 'x' ELSE '' END AS Recieved
             , case when LEGTYPE1 = 2 and answered = 1 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Recieved_Known
             , CASE WHEN ANSWERED = 1 AND LEGTYPE1 = 1 then 'x' ELSE '' end  AS Outbound
             , case when LEGTYPE1 = 1 and FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Outbound_Known
             , case when legtype1 = 2 and answered = 0 and finallycalledpartyno  not like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_No_VM
             , case when finallycalledpartyno like '%oice%' then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_VM
             , case when ANSWERED = 0 and CALLINGPARTYNO = k.phone_number then 'x' ELSE '' end as Missed_Known
             , a.CALLINGPARTYNO AS Calling_Number
             , a.FINALLYCALLEDPARTYNO AS Called_Number
             , b.starttime as Start_Time
             , b.endtime as End_Time
             , b.duration as Talk_Time_Seconds
             , a.holdtimesecs as Hold_Time_Seconds
            row_number() over (partition by a.CALLINGPARTYNO,b.starttime,b.endtime,b.duration order by 1) rn 
            FROM ambition.session a
            INNER JOIN ambition.callsummary b ON a.NOTABLECALLID = b.NOTABLECALLID
            right join jackson_id.users c on a.callingpartyno = c.extension or a.finallycalledpartyno = c.extension
            LEFT JOIN ambition.known_numbers k ON a.callingpartyno = k.phone_number
                WHERE a.ts >= curdate()
                and(a.CALLINGPARTYNO in (select extension from ambition.ambition_users) OR a.finallycalledpartyno IN (select extension from ambition.ambition_users))
            ) x
            where rn = 1
            order by extension;
```